# Two definitions of Lebesgue measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ be bounded interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

1st definition:

Subset $A\subset E$ is measurable if and only if $m^{*} (A)+m^{*}(E\setminus A)=m^* (E)$

2nd definition:

Subset $A\subset E$ is measurable if and only if for each $X\subset E$ we have equality: $m^*(X)=m^*(A\cap X) +m^*((E\setminus A)\cap X)$

I know these are equivalent. The queston is which one is more common in the literature?

Comment: The second one is called "Carathéodory condition". Are you sure that the two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: Sorry... I know where the problem lies. I changed "subset" to "interval"

Comment: Good. You may be interested in [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34007/demystifying-the-caratheodory-approach-to-measurability)